# Why is the munin apache_activity plugin checking /server-status on a different server?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, munin

I have two web servers at different locations (let's call them `WEB1` and `WEB2`) being monitored by the same Munin server.  Today, I noticed the following error in the apache logs for `WEB1`:

```
[error] [client <IP OF WEB2>] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/server-status
```

Naturally, I have server-status limited to localhost on both machines for security.  It happens every 5 minutes at the exact same time my munin server gathers info, so I know it is the munin apache_activity plugin causing this to happen.

Why on earth is it trying to check the server-status of a different server, and how do I stop it?

Comment: Have you checked the plugin configuration files? If `env.url` is set for apache plugins it will use that to grab `/server-status`.

Comment: I don't know much about how Munin works. The only file in `/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/` is `/etc/munin/pluginconf.d/munin-node`.  It has no section header for apache_activity.

Answer (score 0):

apache_activity retrieves "http://127.0.0.1:%d/server-status?auto", so that rules out DNS or /etc/hosts issues (confirm this by looking at your copy of apache_activity.)

Is apache on WEB2 is configured to redirect or proxy some requests to WEB1, and you've inadvertently included /server-status?

Comment: That's what I found too.  I don't have any proxying setup on apache. The only possible link I can think of is that both servers will identify themselves as the root of my domain through apache (i.e. both servers say they're example.com). But both servers also properly identify themselves as WEB1 and WEB2 through telnet to port 4949, and I still have no idea how that would affect the apache_activity plugin.